# How to correctly open file on notification click

Tags: android, notifications

I'm donloading files from the Internet using `IntentService` and displaying a `Notification` while download is in progress. After download complete I need to be able to click on the notification to open downloaded file in appropriate application. Here's a code I'm using for this:

```
Intent intent = IntentUtils.getOpenFileIntent(task.getTargetFolder()
    + File.separator + task.getFileNode().getName());
TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
PendingIntent pi = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(pi);
```

And here's how I create the `Intent`:

```
public static Intent getOpenFileIntent(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String extension = fileExt(path);
    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, type);
    return intent;
}
```

The issue is that tapping on the notification closes any of the currently opened app. I just need to display application chooser over the currently opened app. I think that the issue is in `TaskStackBuilder` usage but there's no other way to create `PendingIntent` instance for `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

Comment: try this: `PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)`

Comment: @SimplePlan thanks, it works! Completly forgotten about this kind of PendingIntent creation. If you add your comment to answers section I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Lingviston where to write the above code?please give me some tips to open the download file from notifications

Comment: @Rajesh use it during notification creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create `PendingIntent` and set to your `Notification`

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
```

Fore more information go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Folder opens, but clicking on the file, It's not opening.
got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
private NotificationManager manager;
private Intent notiIntent;

/// id is integre value which in unique for notifications

notiIntent= new Intent(context, CurrentActiivty.class);
            notiIntent.putExtra("id", id);
            notiIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);



Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "your text on notification bar", System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notiIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,"text here", message, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notiIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        manager.notify(id, notification);
```

Now In calling actiivty write the following code

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int id= extras.getInt("id");
NotificationManager notificationManager;
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(id);
```